# Linear Transformation induced by the following matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose $T:\mathbb R^4\rightarrow\mathbb R^4$ is the transformation induced by the following matrix $A$. Determine whether $T$ is one-to-one and/or onto. If it is not one-to-one, show this by providing two vectors that have the same image under $T$. If $T$ is not onto, show this by providing a vector in $\mathbb R^4$ that is not in the range of $T$.

$$ A = \pmatrix{3&-6&9&3\\-3&6&-6&6\\-2&4&-7&-3\\-1&2&-5&-6}$$

Please help, I reduced the matrix and I can figure out if it is one to one or onto, but I don't know how to get the image under $T$ or whatever it is asking.

Comment: You reduced the matrix? Show us!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the second column of $T$ is just $-2$ times the first column. So if you take the vector $T.(-2,0,0,0)^T$ and $T.(0,1,0,0)^T$ then they are the same. Thus your problem is solved.

However, in general, the easiest way to do these problems is to see if you can find two different vectors $x$ and $y$ such that $Tx=Ty=0$.

Comment: so the same image under T is: T.(−2,0,0,0)T and T.(0,1,0,0)T ?

Comment: @MindOverMatter: You should check that :). All you will need is matrix multiplication. The answer is yes.

Comment: How did you figure this out though? I multiplied these vectors through and got  T.(−2,0,0,0) = ( -6, 6,4,2)....(0,1,0,0) = (-6, 6,4,2) and that is correct. But I do not under understand how you got this, and I do not understand how you get the images under T if it is NOT one to one.

Comment: @MindOverMatter "I do not understand how you got this" -- do you see that $(-6,6,4,2)$ in your matrix?  That's what multiplying by a basis vector does; it isolates a column. Similarly working with $(-2,0,0,0)$ gives the first column multiplied by $-2$.

Comment: Okay, I see it. What about " providing a vector in R4 that is not in the range of T". What does this imply?

Comment: That means you need to find a vector that's not in the range of $T$. Since as we've seen there are linearly dependent column, the range of $T$ will be a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$. You need to identify what that space is, and then you can find a vector that isn't in it.